# /g modifier vs while loop

Tags: regex, perl

I was working out a practice problem from [Google code jam problem](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/351101/dashboard#s=p2) . Whenever I had letters of the same key as `ab` as `11 1` I had to type in a space between them. So I converted each individual letter to the corresponding number sequence and put them in an array. I joined them with ':'. Whenever I had the same digits consecutively separated by ':' I then replace them with ' '. I used the following regex with global modifier.

```
    my $translated = '333:33:3:333'; # edce
    $translated =~ s/(\d+):\g{1}/$1 $1/g;
    print $translated;
```

Output

```
333 33:3 333
```

I had to do the regex again to get the output `333 33 3 333`. I had the global modifier but it doesn't work. I tried a while loop

```
1 while($translated =~ s/(\d+):\g{1}/$1 $1/g);
print $translated
```

Output

```
333 33 3 333
```

Edit :

I get the solution for the problem my question is

**Why doesn't the global modifier work?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The global modifier does work, but we need to be clear how exactly it functions.

When a regex is matched with `/g`, it attempts the next match starting from where the previous match ended.

```
v-- start
333:33:3:333
 ^^^^^        1st match
      |
      v-- start
333 33:3:333
       ^^^    2nd match
          |
          v--start
333 33:3 333
              3rd match fails
```

You can influence which substring is considered to match by using lookaround assertions. Especially, we can change the regex so that only the `:` and not the surrounding digits are matched:

```
(\d+)\K[:](?=\g{-1})
```

How does this work? The `(?=...)` is a zero-width lookahead. The pattern is matched as usual, but the position does not advance from that match. The `\K` operator keeps the current position, will “forget” the previously matched substring. It is similar to a `(?<=...)` lookbehind, except that lookbehinds can only deal with constant-length patterns, which is not the case here.

Then:

```
my $str = "333:33:3:333";
$str =~ s/(\d+)\K[:](?=\g{-1})/ /g;
say $str;
# prints "333 33 3 333"
```

Comment: Thanks @amon. I haven't used lookahead or lookbehind. Could you please post a tutorial link that I can follow..

Comment: @Wordzilla The [`perlretut` (Perl Regex Tutorial)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) has a section on lookaheads and lookbehinds.

Comment: Is `(\d+)\K[:](?=\g{-1})` supposed to match and replace colons also in e.g. [123:323:3:321](http://regex101.com/r/hI5gV7) ? Wouldn't that be similar to just capturing the digit in a lookbehind: `(?<=(\d)):(?=\1)`.

Comment: @Jonny5 yes, all colons in `123:323:3:321` or `123:123:3` would be substituted. I didn't want to change the functionality of the regex in respect to this behavior, so I didn't remove the `+` quantifier. Btw, `\g{…}` is preferable over `\1` because `\g` allows relative references or named patterns.